# Filtering through a multidimensional array using underscore.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, underscore.js

I have an array of `event` objects called `events`. Each `event` has `markets`, an array containing `market` objects. Inside here there is another array called `outcomes`, containing `outcome` objects.

I want to use Underscore.js or some other method to find all of the events which have markets which have outcomes which have a property named `test`.

I imagine this would be achieved using a series of filters but I didn't have much luck!

Comment: Is there any inverse reference? I mean from `outcome` to `market` and so on. Because in this case you can just filter all the `outcome` objects those match your search and go backwards until the `event`, then clean up the array for unique elements.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you can do this using the Underscore.js [`filter`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) and [`some`](http://underscorejs.org/#some) (aka "any") methods:

```
// filter where condition is true
_.filter(events, function(evt) {

    // return true where condition is true for any market
    return _.any(evt.markets, function(mkt) {

        // return true where any outcome has a "test" property defined
        return _.any(mkt.outcomes, function(outc) {
            return outc.test !== undefined ;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I think maybe the user means lodash.js, as I don't see an _.any method in underscore.js http://lodash.com/

Comment: @Fasani it is Underscore, not Lodash.  `_.any` is an alias for `_.some`: http://underscorejs.org/#some

Answer (score 3):

No need for Underscore, you could do this with native JS.

```
var events = [{markets:[{outcomes:[{test:x},...]},...]},...];
return events.filter(function(event) {
    return event.markets.some(function(market) {
        return market.outcomes.some(function(outcome) {
            return "test" in outcome;
        });
    });
});
```

Yet of course you could also use the corresponding underscore methods ([filter/select](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#filter) and [any/some](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/#any)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
_.filter(events, function(me) { 
    return me.event && 
        me.event.market && me.event.market.outcome && 
        'test' in me.event.market.outcome
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SgVqB/)

Answer (score 0):

```js
var events = [
  {
    id: 'a',
    markets: [{
      outcomes: [{
        test: 'yo'
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 'b',
    markets: [{
      outcomes: [{
        untest: 'yo'
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 'c',
    markets: [{
      outcomes: [{
        notest: 'yo'
      }]
    }]
  },
  {
    id: 'd',
    markets: [{
      outcomes: [{
        test: 'yo'
      }]
    }]
  }
];

var matches = events.filter(function (event) {
  return event.markets.filter(function (market) {
    return market.outcomes.filter(function (outcome) {
      return outcome.hasOwnProperty('test');
    }).length;
  }).length;
});

matches.forEach(function (match) {
  document.writeln(match.id);
});
```

Here's how I would do it, without depending on a library:

```
var matches = events.filter(function (event) {
  return event.markets.filter(function (market) {
    return market.outcomes.filter(function (outcome) {
      return outcome.hasOwnProperty('test');
    }).length;
  }).length;
});
```