# Underscore.js .filter() and .any()

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have an array of `event` objects called `events`. Each `event` has `markets`, an array containing `market` objects. Inside here there is another array called `outcomes`, containing `outcome` objects.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10821657/1048572), I asked for a [Underscore.js] way to find all of the events which have markets which have outcomes which have a property named `test`. The answer was:

```
// filter where condition is true
_.filter(events, function(evt) {

    // return true where condition is true for any market
    return _.any(evt.markets, function(mkt) {

        // return true where any outcome has a "test" property defined
        return _.any(mkt.outcomes, function(outc) {
            return outc.test !== "undefined" && outc.test !== "bar";
        });
    });
});
```

This works great, but I'm wondering how I would alter it if I wanted to filter the outcomes for each market, so that `market.outcomes` only stored outcomes that were equal to `bar`. Currently, this is just giving me markets which have outcomes which have **some** set `test` properties. I want to strip out the ones that do not.

Comment: Does it really work great?  Your innermost `.any()` callback references "outcome" but the parameter is "outc" ...

Comment: Also, that aside, it seems like you just need to flip from `.any()` to `.all()` with an opposite condition. In other words, go from "any that are ..." to "all that are not ..."

Comment: Can you provide an example? Not sure what you mean by 'opposite condition'.

Comment: Do you want to remove them from the events / markets array(s) or do you want to create a new structure containing those outcomes?

Comment: Events should only contain markets that have outcomes with a test property. Outcomes should only contain outcomes that have a test property. I want to remove them from the outcomes array if it doesn't have a `test` property.

Comment: I can't exactly tell, but you may be looking for `.map`, as each `events` element should have a different value than it originally has (namely with certain `market` elements removed).

Comment: Can I have an example, please?

Answer (score 5):

Make it a simple loop, using the [splice method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for the array removals:

```
var events = [{markets:[{outcomes:[{test:x},...]},...]},...];
for (var i=0; i<events.length; i++) {
    var mrks = events[i].markets;
    for (var j=0; j<mrks.length; j++) {
        var otcs = mrks[j].outcomes;
        for (var k=0; k<otcs.length; k++) {
            if (! ("test" in otcs[k]))
                 otcs.splice(k--, 1); // remove the outcome from the array
        }
        if (otcs.length == 0)
            mrks.splice(j--, 1); // remove the market from the array
    }
    if (mrks.length == 0)
        events.splice(i--, 1); // remove the event from the array
}
```

This code will remove all outcomes that have no `test` property, all empty markets and all empty events from the `events` array.

An Underscore version might look like that:

```
events = _.filter(events, function(evt) {
    evt.markets = _.filter(evt.markets, function(mkt) {
        mkt.outcomes = _.filter(mkt.outcomes, function(otc) {
            return "test" in otc;
        });
        return mkt.outcomes.length > 0;
    });
    return evt.markets.length > 0;
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. However, can this be achieved with Underscore (seeing as I'm already using the library elsewhere and the code would probably be a lot more readable).

Comment: Yes, it's possible. But the underscore filter function creates new array instances, which then will overwrite the obsolete arrays, instead of just deleting items from them.

Comment: @Kloar: It just may or may not be what is needed, the difference can be significant.